# How prove this inequality with $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1,-1<a_{i}<1(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$

Tags: inequality

I have solve following problem:

let $a_{i}>0,(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$,and such $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=1$,show that
$$F=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\dfrac{a_{i}a_{j}}{(1-a_{i})(1-a_{j})}\ge\dfrac{n}{2n-2}$$
Proof:use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have (let $t_{i}=a_{i}(1-a_{i})$)
$$4F\ge\dfrac{\left(2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i}a_{j}\right)^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i}(1-a_{i})a_{j}(1-a_{j})}=\dfrac{(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i})^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}t_{i}t_{j}}$$
it is enough to  prove that
$$(n-1)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i})^2\ge 2n\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}t_{i}t_{j}$$
or
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}t^2_{i}\ge (\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i})^2$$ it is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!

My problem:I found this problem is also for $a_{i}\in (-1,1)(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$,and $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1$.we have
$$F=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\dfrac{a_{i}a_{j}}{(1-a_{i})(1-a_{j})}\ge\dfrac{n}{2n-2}\tag{1}$$

this case we can't use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to solve it.because this $a_{i}(1-a_{i})a_{j}(1-a_{j})$ maybe is $<0$.so How to prove $(1)$

Comment: If $a_1=1, a_2 = \cdots = a_n=0$, $F$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @NeatMath,oh,I forgot this case. and I  have edit it

Comment: http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/MTProblem1.pdf

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h363142p1992608

Comment: in Aops, I think the arqady solution is wrong,because Cauchy-Schwarz inequality not hold all real numbers.

Comment: @inequality cauchy schwarz inequality is valid for all real numbers its proof is a simple sum of squares

Comment: I wonder if there is still a point in trying to achieve solutions to this problem, given that links to existing solutions are already given. If in doubt about those solutions, it would rather make sense to take one of these solutions and ask for a proof verification.